# Shortening if() with string.equals method

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there any way to shorten this `if()` statement? To avoid repeating `string.equals()` somehow?

```
if (extension.equals("jpg") || extension.equals("JPG") || extension.equals("png") || extension.equals("PNG") || extension.equals("bmp") || extension.equals("BMP") || extension.equals("jpeg") || extension.equals("JPEG"))
{
    tmp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/menage/Resources/imageIco.png")));
}
```

To something looking similar to this :

```
if (extension.equals(("jpg")||("JPG")||("png")||("PNG")||("bmp")||("BMP")||("jpeg")||("JPEG")))
{
    tmp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/menage/Resources/imageIco.png"));)
}
```

I am aware that this question looks odd, however `if()` with such long conditions list is unclear and requires a lot of writing as well.

Comment: you could try packing the different options into a `List` and check it via `List#contains`. A `switch` statement might also shorten it a little.

Comment: you can use switch instead

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by changing `equals(...)` to `equalsIgnoreCase(...)`.

Other options, create a HashSet of lower case Strings (or upper case if desired) with your image extensions and see if it contains your String of interest, changed to lower case:

```
if (imageExtSet.contains(myExtension.toLowerCase()) {

}
```

Comment: You could use a constant collection. `public static final List<String> VALID_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS = Arrays.asList("JPG", "GIF", "PNG");`

Comment: @Matt `Set<String>` will perform better than `List<String>`. This is the way to go for these cases. Sadly, seems like people prefer to naively use `List` or array for the job =\.

Answer (score 4):

Here is short version with predefined image types:

```
Set<String> imgTypes = new HashSet<>() {{ 
  add("jpg");   add("JPG");
  add("png");   add("PNG");
  add("bmp");   add("BMP");
  add("jpeg");  add("JPEG");
}};

public boolean isImgType(String type) {
  return imgTypes.contains(type);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can keep all values in a list and then asks if contains. If it's only a one liner (you don't need to ask for this condition anywhere else), you can do:

```
if (Arrays.asList("jpg", "JPG", "png", "PNG", "bmp", "BMP", "jpeg", "JPEG").contains(extension))
```

You can of course save the list as an object and then anywhere you need to ask for this condition reference it.

Comment: While this works, it's better to use a `Set` to *speed* it up (but who counts some milliseconds, I wonder?).

Comment: you should probably use ``extension.toLowerCase()* and maintain a list of all lower case values so you don't have to repeat all possible casings

Answer (score 2):

Use HashSet
Like this

```
Set<String> extSet= new HashSet<String>();
// Add All in Lower case .. to save your efforts

extSet.add("jpg");
extSet.add("png");

//...etc etc
```

and just check if it is present in the Set

```
if(extSet.contains(extension==null?null:extension.toLowerCase()))
{
/// True
}
else
{
// False
}
```

Comment: Nice touch to check whether the extension is null! You could create the set like this: `final Set<String> ext = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("png", "jpg"));`. You could use the following check: `if (extension != null && extSet.contains(extension.toLowerCase()))`, but that's almost the same as your code.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to eliminate some checks, is to convert the string to lower case:

```
String ext = extension.toLowerCase();
```

Now you have shorten the statement to:

```
if (ext.equals("jpg") || ext.equals("png") || ext.equals("bmp") || ext.equals("jpeg"))
```

Comment: This breaks horribly if `ext` is `null`.

Comment: Great, noted. Next time your code breaks, I know you will say *that wasn't asked, so I didn't do it* :)

Comment: That's simple to fix: "jpg".equals(ext)

Comment: It is a classic but very useful defensive technique.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Arrays.asList("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp").contains(extension.toLowerCase))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in some methods...

```
private static boolean isJpeg(String ext) {
    return java.util.Arrays.asList("jpg", "jpeg").contains(ext.toLowerCase());
}

private static boolean isPng(String ext) {
    return "png".equalsIgnoreCase(ext);
}

private static boolean isBmp(String ext) {
    return "bmp".equalsIgnoreCase(ext);
}
```

And change it to...

```
else if (isJpeg(extension) || isPng(extension) || isBmp(extension))
            {
                tmp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/menage/Resources/imageIco.png")));
            }
```

The `isJpeg` will throw a `NullPointerException` if the extention is null, so ensure it's not null by adding `extension != null || ...` or something.

---

The above is slightly different for your specific case as it allows `JpEg` and all other mixed capitalizations to slip through. If you don't want that, use these. Plus, the below have the added benefit of never throwing `NullPointerException` if the extension is `null`.

```
private static boolean isJpeg(String ext) {
    return java.util.Arrays.asList("jpg", "JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG").contains(ext);
}

private static boolean isPng(String ext) {
    return java.util.Arrays.asList("png", "PNG").contains(ext);
}

private static boolean isBmp(String ext) {
    return java.util.Arrays.asList("bmp", "BMP").contains(ext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers give lots of good low-level ideas, but the basic principle here is to prevent code reuse.

**If you are doing this test more than once, create a method that does the test for you:**

```
boolean isValidImageExtenstion(String extension) {
    return (extension.equals("jpg") || extension.equals("JPG") ||
            extension.equals("png") || extension.equals("PNG") ||
            extension.equals("bmp") || extension.equals("BMP") ||
            extension.equals("jpeg") || extension.equals("JPEG"));
}
```

Call the method whenever you need it. If you like you can use one of the approaches described in the other answers within the method, (and the 'ignore case' suggestion is certainly worth it) but the rest become less important now that you have prevented the code repetition. As a bonus, if you decide you want to support gif extensions you only have to make the change in one place.

The advantages of this approach over the others are that it is self-documenting. It's pretty obvious what the method does, and some of the other answers are pretty obscure.

If you are only doing this once, and don't intend to do it again, then you have already created working code, so **don't waste your time modifying working code**.

Comment: I believe it is worthwhile to refactor working code to be more readable. OP's specific example is probably fine as is, but `if` statements can get unreadable in a hurry. If code is readable it's easier to check when the next person comes to it.